# How elastic-search partial snapshots work

Tags: elasticsearch

If I keep on taking snapshots , and lets assume the first two snapshots ended up in being partial snapshots and third one succeeds , then can I delete those partial snapshots and be able to restore everything from the third snapshot? Or do i need to keep all the snapshots ?

Will I be able to just refer to the third snapshots for restoring indices [elastic will look it up for me in partial snapshots if not present in the final one? ] or do I need to go explicitly to those partial snapshots for some of the indices to be restored?

```
fullsnap-201902 PARTIAL 1547497447  20:24:07   1547498721 20:45:21    21.2m     163               417             6          423
fullsnap-201903 PARTIAL 1547498746  20:45:46   1547499531 20:58:51      13m     163               420             3          423
fullsnap-201904 SUCCESS 1547500210  21:10:10   1547500864 21:21:04    10.8m     163               423             0          423
```

Answer (score 1):

A PARTIAL snapshot indicates an error condition, more precisely that the data for some shard could not be backed up. So before attempting any restore you should first investigate why those partial snapshots happens in the first place by looking at the `failure` section of the snapshot response.

If you attempt to restore a PARTIAL snapshot (using `partial: true`), then shards that could not be snapshotted in the first place will be recreated empty, which is probably not what you're looking for.

To sum up:

1. I would first investigate why your snapshot was PARTIAL
2. I would only try to restore snapshots that ended up in SUCCESS

Comment: Ok, so I can delete thoese partial snapshots and keep the last one that succeeds?

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: why it takes very long for the first snapshot , even that ended up in partial and the last one was so quick and succeesful? I think the last one is somehow pointing to the prevous ones?

Comment: Impossible to say what happened if you don't have access to the failures in the response

Comment: I know why it fails , there are tcp timeouts for the minio s3 endpoint , but i want to know if there is some relationship between these snapshots , because it took more than 3 hour for first one ( not shown there ) and then less for subsequesnt ones ( few minutes )

Comment: partial snapshots are ok , I keep taking them untill I get a full succefful snapshot , from which I can restore any index. I also worked around the problem by having separate monthly snaps instead of including everything in every snap

Comment: I'm trying to delete partial snapshots, but ES is not allowing me, it is giving error: "Blob [index-0] already exists, cannot overwrite".

Comment: @ljaz Ahmad Khan, I'm also looking for monthly snapshot/restoration process, can you help me on that? I couldn't find a way to restore more than one snapshot, If my index is spread across multiple snapshots, while restoring 2nd snapshot it is expecting me to delete/rename the index that was restored from 1st snapshot. (I have tried it using complete snapshots, not with incremental).